# Monitor and update number of active processes

Tags: java, process

I'm trying to create a program that is able to create .jar and .exe processes and monitor how many of those processes are active. The way I'm using to monitor those processes is by adding them to a list and getting it's size, but I'm having trouble updating the number of active processes once their window is closed, I guess the waitFor() method cannot be used because I have multi-processes, should I use the exitValue() in an iteration of the processes list to check if they have been terminated?

Comment: you could use the waitFor() method of a Process, if you have a shared resource containing the count of active processes, and the processes themselves are started and joined on with .waitFor() by asynchronous threads, which update the shared resource when .waitFor() returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to go along with my comment. Pretty strait forward, although I would clean up this code if you plan on using it in a production environment.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainTest {

JLabel countLabel = new JLabel("");
Thread printer = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // passes in a directory

    MainTest test = new MainTest();
}

public MainTest() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestFrame");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(200, 200, 200, 200));
    JButton button = new JButton("Open Instances");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    OpenStuff();
                }

            });
            t.start();
        }

    });
    countLabel.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

    panel.add(countLabel);
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    panel.add(button);
    printer = new Thread(new CountPrinter());
    printer.start();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.show();
}

private void OpenStuff() {
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    while (count < 5) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new OpenNotePadAndJoin());
        t.start();
        threads.add(t);
        count++;
    }

    for (Thread t : threads) {
        try {
            t.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    printer.interrupt();
}

private static class SharedResource {
    public static volatile int count = 0;
}

private class CountPrinter implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            countLabel.setText(String.valueOf(SharedResource.count));
            countLabel.getParent().repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

private class OpenNotePadAndJoin implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad");
        try {

            Process p = pb.start();
            SharedResource.count++;
            p.waitFor();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            SharedResource.count--;
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I get it, I was only focusing on the Process methods and the List of Threads is a much cleaner solution than the one I had, thank you.

Comment: I've tried to integrate the code you supplied into a JFrame interface , but I don't think it's possible because the waitFor() blocks the interface, at least I think so. I'll have to create another way to implement an asynchronous threading implementation.

Comment: just dont call .waitFor() with the gui thread, and you should be fine.

Comment: got it, it wasn't working for me because I wasn't starting the program as a thread, that caused the GUI to not respond when I started a single instance of the program. I had to close the opened program to be able to unlock the GUI and start a new one, thanks a lot and have a happy new year.